# How to add a delay for button.click Javascript call

Tags: javascript

I have the following script that I run on Console mode in Chrome to automatically click on some buttons on the webpage.
But I want to add a delay after each click so that it won't click all buttons at once.
Please let me know how to proceed.

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.button')).forEach(function(button) {button.click();});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález as far as I know it all will "burst" after specified delay.

Comment: @Sergey He has to add different defays to each button, or better, execute the next button click after each delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the request `requestAnimationFrame` function

```
delay(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.button')));

function delay(sequentialEvents) {
    if (sequentialEvents.length > 0) {
        requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            var btn = sequentialEvents.shift();
            btn.click();
            delay(sequentialEvents);
        });
    }
}
```

or the `setTimeout` function

```
delay(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.button')), 1000);

function delay(sequentialEvents, ms) {
    if (sequentialEvents.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var btn = sequentialEvents.shift();
            btn.click();
            delay(sequentialEvents, ms);
        }, ms);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are. Try this one. Just made checkboxes instead of buttons to make it obvious.

```js
var buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')];

function clickButton(buttons) {

  var len = buttons.length;

  if (len < 1) return false;
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    buttons[0].click();
    buttons.splice(0,1);
    clickButton(buttons);
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = clickButton(buttons);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```